# Is the braid category biclosed and bicomplete?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the braid category, as in *Categories for the Working Mathematician* §XI.4 p.262 (objects are natural numbers and morphisms are the braids $n\to n$).
Then this can be given a natural braided monoidal category structure $(\mathcal{B},\otimes,\varnothing)$, where $\otimes$ corresponds to addition (on objects) and 'laying braids side by side' (on morphisms).

I would like to know if this monoidal category is **bicomplete** and/or **biclosed** (that is, for all objects $n\in\mathcal{B}$ the functor $-\otimes n$ has a right adjoint $[n,-]$, and similarly for $n\otimes-$).
I have been looking for a reference, but can't seem to find anything apart from MacLane, so any of a reference, a sketch proof, or even just an out-of-the-blue claim would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functor $-\otimes n$ (or $-\otimes n$) has no right (or left) adjoint for any $n>0$.  Indeed, every morphism in the braid category is and endomorphism, so there exists a map $i\otimes n\to j$ iff $i+n=j$.  So if an adjoint existed, $[n,j]$ would have to satisfy $[n,j]=i$ iff $i+n=j$, but this is impossible for any $j<n$.

Comment: wonderfully succinct, thanks!